# change client data transforms value in meteor.js

Tags: d3.js, meteor

In my current meteor.js project, user can create a project and add data nodes to it. I'm using D3 to display the nodes in force graph. When they click a particular node from the graph, the corresponding text in the side panel must be highlighted. For this, I need to track with node is selected. But, I don't want to store a "selected" field on the database.

I'm using this data transform to add selected field right now -

/lib/routes.js

```
Router.route('/project/:code', {
    name: 'projectPage',
    data: function() { 
            return {
                project: Projects.findOne({code : this.params.code}), 
                nodes: Nodes.find({project: this.params.code}, {transform: function (doc) {
                       doc.selected = false;
                       return doc;
                    }})
            }

        }
});
```

The template is /client/templates/projectPage.html

```
<template name="projectPage">
  <div class="project-page page">
    <h3>{{project.title}}</h3>
    <p>{{project.summary}}</p>
    <div class="work-area">
        <div class="map-space">
            {{> nodeDisplay nodes=nodes}}
        </div>
        <div class="type-space">
            {{> typeDisplay nodes=nodes}}
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<template name="nodeDisplay">
   <div id="svgdiv"></div>
</template>

<template name="typeDisplay">
    {{#each nodesData}}
        <p>{{text}}</p>
        <br/>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

The click event is handled /client/js/projects.js

```
Template.nodeDisplay.events({
    'click .node':function(event, template){
        /*remove previous selection*/
        d3.selectAll('.selected circle').attr("r",32);
        d3.selectAll('.selected').each(
            function(d){
                d.fixed = false;
                d3.select(this)
                .classed('selected', false);
            }
        );

        /*add new selections*/
        d3.select(event.currentTarget)
        .classed("selected", true)
        d3.selectAll('.selected circle').attr("r",40);
        var selected_id = $(event.currentTarget).data("id");
        Nodes.update(selected_id.toString(), {$set: {selected: true}});
    }
});
```

However, this updates the database to include the "selected" field. 
Is there a better way to do this and keep reactivity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meteor way is to use session variables and helper functions.

So instead of

```
Nodes.update(selected_id.toString(), {$set: {selected: true}});
```

use

```
Session.set("selected_node", this._id);
```

and an accompnying helper in Template.typeDisplay.helpers

```
isNodeSelected: function() {
  if(Session.get("selected_node") === this._id) {
    return "selected"
  }
}
```

in the template displaying each node (this code assumes that you want to select the corresponding text in the typeDisplay by applying the classname 'selected'):

```
<template name="typeDisplay">
  {{#each nodesData}}
    <p class="{{isNodeSelected}}">{{text}}</p>
    <br/>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```